# Find count of maximum consecutive records based on one field in Mongodb Query

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I want to find the count of maximum consecutive records based on one particular field.

My `db.people` collection after finding sort based on field is:

```
> db.people.find().sort({ updated_at: 1})
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "aaa", "flag" : true, "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-02-07T08:42:48.688Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "bbb", "flag" : false, "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-02-07T08:43:10Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "ccc", "flag" : true, "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-02-07T08:43:40.660Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "ddd", "flag" : true, "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-02-07T08:43:51.567Z") }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "fff", "flag" : false, "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-02-07T08:44:23.713Z") }
{ "_id" : 7, "name" : "ggg", "flag" : true, "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-02-07T08:44:44.639Z") }
{ "_id" : 8, "name" : "hhh", "flag" : true, "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-02-07T08:44:51.415Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "eee", "flag" : true, "updated_at" : ISODate("2014-02-07T08:55:24.917Z") }
```

In above records, there are two places where `flag` attribute value comes `true` in consecutive ways. i.e

```
record with _id 3 - record with _id 4   (2 consecutive records)
```

and

```
record with _id 7 - record with _id 8 - record with _id 5  (3 consecutive records)
```

However, I want the maximum consecutive number from mongo query search. i.e `3`.

Is it possible to get such result?

I googled it and found a little similar solution of using [`Map-Reduce`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408639/1120530.

I am new to mongodb and couldn't able to understand the `map-reduce` documentation and specially how to apply it in above scenario.

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean 'most consecutive records' when ordered by particular key fields or are you looking for a natural order of insertion. It helps if people understand your use case when asking a question. This avoids you saying later that the response wan't exactly what you wanted.

Comment: you can achieve it with javascript expression(note that it will be slow). there is no mongo native query as far as I know.

Comment: Do these really have in incremental numeric _id ? And _id is the sort key right? I'm a skeptic for things that are too easy.

Comment: @NeilLunn: 'updated_at' is the sort key and '_id' is not incremental numeric values.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to this a lot later than intended. But I think the answer should suffice.

Comment: We can see that you have visited this site on several occasions since an answer was submitted. If this does not meet your expectations then please comment. It seems a shame for you to throw away your reputation points from the bounty on this when you actually receive an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this mapReduce operation.

First the mapper:

```js
var mapper = function () {


    if ( this.flag == true ) {
        totalCount++;
    } else {
        totalCount = 0;
    }

    if ( totalCount != 0 ) {
        emit (
        counter,
        {  _id: this._id, totalCount: totalCount }
    );
    } else {
      counter++;
    }

};
```

Which keeps a running count of the total times that the `true` value is seen in flag. If that count is more than 1 then we emit the the value, also containing the document `_id`. Another counter which is used for the key is incremented when the flag is `false`, in order to have a grouping "key" for the matches.

Then the reducer:

```js
var reducer = function ( key, values ) {

    var result = { docs: [] };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result.docs.push(value._id);
        result.totalCount = value.totalCount;
    });

    return result;

};
```

Simply pushes the `_id` values onto a result array along with the totalCount.

Then run:

```js
db.people.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    reducer,
   { 
       "out": { "inline": 1 }, 
       "scope": { 
           "totalCount": 0, 
           "counter": 0 
       }, 
       "sort": { "updated_at": 1 } 
   }
)
```

So with the `mapper` and `reducer` functions, we then define the global variables used in "scope" and pass in the "sort" that was required on `updated_at` dates. Which gives the result:

```js
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "value" : {
                "docs" : [
                     3,
                     4
                 ],
                 "totalCount" : 2
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "value" : {
            "docs" : [
                7,
                8,
                5
             ],
             "totalCount" : 3
             }
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 2,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 7,
            "emit" : 5,
            "reduce" : 2,
            "output" : 2
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Of course you could just skip the `totalCount` variable and just use the array length, which would be the same. But since you want to use that counter anyway it's just added in. But that's the principle.

So yes, this was a problem suited to mapReduce, and now you have an example.

Comment: @NeilLunn, Nice answer, and where are you dude?