# Mongo DB - usage of map reduce or aggregation

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have series of documents in MongoDB collection that looks like this:

```
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:12:00', 'value' : 90 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:13:00', 'value' : 82 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:14:00', 'value' : 75 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:15:00', 'value' : 72 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:16:00', 'value' : 81 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:17:00', 'value' : 90 },
etc....
```

The tasks is - with trash hold value of 80 find all times where value is `entering` below 80 and `exiting` above 80

```
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:14:00', 'result' : 'enter' },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:16:00', 'result' : 'exit' },
```

Is it way to have map reduce or aggregation query that would produce such result ?
I was trying to loop thru sorted results, but it is very processing and memory expensive - I need to do series of such checks.

PS. I am using Django and mongoengine to execute call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find count of maximum consecutive records based on one field in Mongodb Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621754/find-count-of-maximum-consecutive-records-based-on-one-field-in-mongodb-query)?

Comment: Not voting that as a "dup" ( yet ), because your case here is a little unclear. It would seem that sequential iteration is all you really want. You can sort of "force" mapReduce to spit out results like the example does here, but unless you are really gaining something then you probably should not. Note that the aggregation framework simply cannot "track" between documents like you need to here.

Comment: Are there any duplicates in the field `time`? What will be the `result` if the `value` is 80?

Comment: well, in case of `value` is 80, I'm reading it as "exclude" based on OP description.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is possible with the MongoDB aggregation framework alone since, as mentioned by @BlakesSeven, there is no link/connection between the subsequent documents. And you need this connection to check if the new value went below or above the desired threshold comparing to what the value was right before it, in a previous document.

Here is a naive *pure-python* (since it is tagged with Django and MongoEngine) solution that loops over the sorted results maintaining the threshold-track variable and catching when it goes lower or higher 80 (`col` is your collection reference):

```
THRESHOLD = 80
cursor = col.find().sort("time")

first_value = next(cursor)
more_than = first_value["value"] >= THRESHOLD

for document in cursor:
    if document["value"] < THRESHOLD:
        if more_than:
            print({"time": document["time"], "result": "enter"})
        more_than = False
    else:
        if not more_than:
            print({"time": document["time"], "result": "exit"})
        more_than = True
```

For the provided sample data, it prints:

```
{'time': '2016-03-28 12:14:00', 'result': 'enter'}
{'time': '2016-03-28 12:16:00', 'result': 'exit'}
```

---

As a side note and an alternative solution..if you have control over the how these records are inserted, when you insert a document into this collection, you may check what is the latest `value`, compare it to the threshold and set the `result` as a separate field. Then, querying the entering and exiting the threshold points would become as easy as:

```
col.find({"result" : {$exists : true}})
```

You can name this approach as "marking the threshold values beforehand". This probably makes sense only from querying/searching performance perspective and if you are going to do this often.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve transformation of documents easily with help of aggregation framework and cursor iteration.

Example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project:
    {
      value:1,
      "threshold":{$let:
        {
          vars: {threshold: 80 }, 
          in:   "$$threshold"
        }}
     }
  },
  {$match:{value:{$ne: "$threshold"}}},
  {$group:
     {
       _id:"$null", 
       low:{
         $max:{
             $cond:[{$lt:["$value","$threshold"]},"$value",-1]
          }
       },

       high:{
         $min:{
             // 10000000000 is a superficial value. 
             // need something greater than values in documents
             $cond:[{$gt:["$value","$threshold"]},"$value",10000000000] 
          }
       },

       threshold:{$first:"$threshold"}
     }
   }  
])
```

Aggregation framework will return a document with two values.

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "low" : NumberInt(75), 
    "high" : NumberInt(81), 
    "threshold" : NumberInt(80)
}
```

We can easily find documents matching return criteria. e.g. in NodeJS we can easily do this. assuming variable **`result`** holds result from aggregation query.

```
result.forEach(function(r){

   var documents = [];

   db.collection.find({$or:[{"value": r.low},{"value": r.high}]}).forEach(function(doc){

        var _doc = {};
        _doc.time = doc.time;
        _doc.result = doc.value < r.threshold ? "enter" : "exit";
        documents.push(_doc);
   });
   printjson(documents);
});
```

As you mention, if your input documents are (sample)

```
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:12:00', 'value' : 90 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:13:00', 'value' : 82 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:14:00', 'value' : 75 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:15:00', 'value' : 72 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:16:00', 'value' : 81 },
{ 'time' : '2016-03-28 12:17:00', 'value' : 90 },
etc....
```

Query above in solution will emit:

```
{
    "time" : "2016-03-28 12:14:00", 
    "result" : "enter"
}, 
{
    "time" : "2016-03-28 12:16:00", 
    "result" : "exit"
}
```